# What does "<8>" mean as a value?

Tags: vb.net, exception

I'm getting an exception report from a vb.net Windows Forms app I made via the exception reporting system I built into it. Some users are getting an exception with message "Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.Couldn't store <8> in PrdHrs Column.  Expected type is Decimal."

The stack trace included tells me the method, and that message narrows down where the exception is being hit, but I can't figure out what "<8>" means. Does that just mean the value of 8, but it's displayed with less than/greater than symbols around it? Or does that imply a certain value type? Google is basically impossible to search for this.

Comment: It's certainly nothing that I've seen before. I wonder whether it is supposed to represent infinity, which is like an 8 on its side. Perhaps you could provide the code that generates the exception and we may be able to work it out from that. The code is ALWAYS relevant.

Comment: Also, the message talks about a column. Column of what? Is this data being stored in a `DataTable`? FULL and CLEAR explanation please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that that '8' actually is an infinity symbol but it's not displayed properly in whatever you're seeing.  I just tried this code:

```
Dim dbl = Double.PositiveInfinity
Dim table As New DataTable

table.Columns.Add("Number", GetType(Decimal))

table.Rows.Add(dbl)
```

and this was the message I got:

> System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057   Message=Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.Couldn't store <∞> in
>   Number Column.  Expected type is Decimal.   Source=System.Data
>   StackTrace:    at System.Data.DataColumn.set_Item(Int32 record, Object
>   value)    at System.Data.DataTable.NewRecordFromArray(Object[] value) 
>   at System.Data.DataRowCollection.Add(Object[] values)    at
>   ConsoleApp1.Module1.Main() in C:\Users\johnm\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\ConsoleApp1\Module1.vb:line 12
>
> Inner Exception 1: OverflowException: Value was either too large or
>   too small for a Decimal.

It's not ideal that you are working with `Double` values and then storing the results as `Decimal` values.  It may be unavoidable but, if so, you need to do a bit better at validation.  You are probably dividing by zero, which is legal for `Double` values and produces either `Double.PositiveInfinity` or `Double.NegativeInfinity`.

Comment: That's a pretty good catch. :-) I wouldn't have suspected that was the problem reading the question, but your example shows that it could very well be. Nice! :-)